# Ideal way for implementing server side of push notification using .Net

Tags: c#, .net

In One of my web application, I need to push ToDo type of information on server database, to the client as push notification. What will be the efficient way of invoking a push notification call. Should it be a standalone `Windows service` that can track the data in the database, every few minutes and invoke the Push notification call via GCM or APNS. or is there any other better way of doing this.

The application can run on both internet or intranet environment. This is not an event based notification, The data in the database need to monitor frequently and invoke the push notification service if required.

Comment: you could implement a duplex wcf service.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You question is a little _broad_.  Are we talking about an intranet or Internet system?

Comment: it is internet based system. should work on intranet system. I will make my question more elaborate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal answer: It depends...

- Do you have any mechanisms that can detect when it is time to send the push notification? Like a message that gets dropped in a queue, a file that gets created, an event triggered from a SQL Server Broker, etc. ?

If the answer is YES, then you probably should use this mechanism to trigger sending your push notification.

If the answer is NO, then you probably will end up with a Windows Service that queries a database (or some other store) every few seconds/minutes/hours

Comment: This is not an event based notification. (I just updated my question). Thanks

Comment: @bashahul Right. In that case (as I mentioned above) you'll have to build a Windows Service to continuously query the database every X time to discover notifications to send, send them, and then flag something in the DB so you don't keep sending the same notifications...